# Laravel Excel - how to remove a row by row number?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

I am using **Laravel Excel** package with **Laravel 5.2**. I've loaded an `.xls` file and can read cell values.

Code:

```
Excel::load($file, function($reader) {

    $sheet = $reader->getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    echo 'value: '.$sheet->getCell('B9');

})->store('xls', storage_path('excel/exports'));
```

Now If a cell value contains specific text, **I want to remove that row** and save as a new file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this

```
 $reader->skip(10)->take(1);

// Limit with skip and take
$reader->($skip, $take);
```

Comment: Can you please explain what skip and take do?

Comment: if you want to get the 11th row skip 10 and get 1

Comment: sorry. it's not working as I am expecting. It does not remove the row from the excel file.